# Was Michael Van Patrick super powered?

Tags: comics, marvel, avengers, avengers-initiative

Michael Van Patrick was a character from Avenger's initiative. He never showed any particular 'super power'  so why was he part of the initiative?

Comment: Ironman and Hawkeye are also not super-powered.

Comment: But both have superpowered/human abilities or items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He was part of the initiative probably due to being the great grand-son of the creator of the super soldier serum which created Captain America. He has no super powers though he's an outstanding human-being:

> In Avengers: The Initiative #2, Dr. Baron Von Blitzschlag refers to
>   Michael Van Patrick as an "Übermensch", a perfect human specimen, down
>   to the cellular level. This perfection is displayed in his mental and
>   physical abilities being the highest possible standard for a human
>   being to be without being considered superhuman, much like Captain
>   America.

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Van_Patrick)